# Django ORM - updating specific instance with a user-ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I have the following model setup:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    val1_1 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    val1_2 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='model1')

class Model2(models.Model):
    val2_1 = models.BinaryField()
    model1_link = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='model2')

class Model3(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    model2_link = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='model3')
    val3_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Model4(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    model3_link = models.ForeignKey(Model3, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='model4', null=True, default=None)
    pred = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    # These fields are NOT FILLED IN during creation of an instance, and are instead updated later on with a separate query
    disputed_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    suggested_by = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='submitted_disputes', blank=True, null=True)
```

At times, I will want to access Model4's specific instance, to actually fill in a value in fields disputed_on & suggested_by, by traversing all the way from Model1. I do that currently as such:

```
query = Model1.objects.filter(id=some_chosen_id).get().model2.last().model3.filter(val3_1=some_chosen_value).get().model4.last()
```

The output of that query is a single model instance, not a QuerySet.
Next, I calculate new values I want to insert:

```
dispute_date = datetime.now(tz.tzutc())

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    disputer = request.user
else:
    # Assume admin (first entry)
    disputer = User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

And I save new values by doing the following:

```
query.disputed_on = dispute_date
query.suggested_by = disputer

query.save()
```

Now, the strangest thing happens - my postgres DB gives me an error stating, the following:

```
postgres_1  | 2020-03-30 11:45:31.700 AEDT [4169] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_user_username_key"
```

Now, the way I read it, calling prediction.save() also results in DB trying to update table of users. But I do not call for that anywhere in the code!

Any ideas why is that happening?

That problem seems to be gone when I modify my query to stay as a QuerySet, and use .update() method instead...

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: Um, I have already changed the code to keep query as a QuerySet and migrated everything in the models. I'd have to break the code again to reproduce it. I have asked this question just as an educational opportunity, to learn if I was doing something incorrectly with the non-QuerySet approach.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have a signal handler somewhere that is doing something on save. `update()` does not trigger signals